# How to handle JSON custom Parse Push Notifications in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform, notifications

I'm looking for a smooth way on how to handle a custom **Push notifications**, I'm using **Parse** as a backend for my application and I'm sending the **Push Notification** in **JSON**.

I'm using this function to handle the **Notification Received**.

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
        if let info = userInfo["data"] as? Dictionary <String, String> {
             let message = info["message"]! as String
              MainFunctions.showbanner("Notification", subtitle: message) // Just showing the notification message when the app is foreground

        }

        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
        }
    }
```

My question is how to know if the application is in Foreground or in Background, and how to show the notification depending on that, I was able to show the notification when the application is in foreground.

**How to do that when the application is in Background ? and how to know that the application in in Background.**

Comment: did you get the answer